# How many Vertica Databases can run on a Host in the same time?

Tags: instance, database-schema, vertica

I know in Oracle i can have multiple homes running on the same host ?
Can this be done in Vertica to ?
 i am running CE vertion of Vertica and it seems i can not do this !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't allow multiple databases within a single instance of vertica to be active; it makes sense that they wouldn't allow multiple instance of vertica, resulting in multiple databases, active at the same time.

EDIT: Reasons I say it makes sense: Vertica can be resource intensive. It is designed to deal with A LOT of data. Having multiple 'Verticas' fighting for disk, cpu, bandwidth is going to negatively impact performance for all of them.

Comment: Why would this make sense ? Is it because of the license ?? maybe !!

Comment: Yeah.  Vertica is designed to use the resources it's given on each node; trying to divide them up between multiple Vertica instances would just make them fight each other.  Instead, if you want to run two databases, divide your nodes so each node is only part of one cluster.  CE only goes up to three nodes anyway, so if you've got more than that you've got spare capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember, Vertica is a distributed database unlike Oracle. Therefore you have an instance in each of your cluster node and the cluster has access to larger disk storage. Distributed databases are best used if data of various apps stays in a single cluster as each instance takes up lot of CPU for data compression, read/write optimized stores, and delivering performance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run multiple databases in a Vertica cluster. That said, there are no set limits on the number of schemas you can run in a single database. Considering how many users and how much data can be handled by a single Vertica cluster (with one database), I would need a very compelling reason why multiple databases are necessary. It rather like complaining that a house doesn't have three kitchens, one each for breakfast lunch and dinner.