# Is there a workaround to Vertica's limitation of one database at a time?

Tags: database, vertica

We are new to Vertica and found it relatively surprising that only one database at a time can be UP/active. In our research work we need to access multiple databases at a time, so I'd like to know how other Vertica users manage this [limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549211/how-many-vertica-databases-can-run-on-a-host-in-the-same-time). The only approaches I've thought of so far are a) taking turns (start and stop databases as needed), or b) (mis-)using schemas to group tables into logical databases. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have multiple databases. Each database would need dedicated nodes. With a 6 node cluster:

```
DB1 on node1, node2, node3
DB2 on node4, node5, node6
```

In order to maintain [high availability](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConceptsGuide/Components/HighAvailabilityAndRecovery.htm), each database would require at least 3 nodes for a K-Safety level of 1. If the databases loses a node with K-level 1, the database will run normally.

The way Vertica is designed is intended for a single database instance. Vertica falls under the MPP (Massively Parallel Processing) category. Multiple databases would be competing for resources on a cluster. The parallel design enables the distribution of storage and workload across the nodes. The best design is to logically create your schemas like you would databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can run more then one Vertica database even on the same node !! Yo just need to alter the port number where the database run on !! 
 But like @FreshPrinceOfSO said Vertica is quite hungry for resources (Memory in special). So is recomended to keep your Cluster with one database running on it!!! 
 I prefer to create a new cluster insted of mixing up the schemas !! Or if you choose to create schemas to behave like database repos you need to have a good knowladge of your resource management tasks!